# Using GEOS concave hull algorithm from Python

Tags: python, geos, concave-hull

I don't want to reinvent the wheel; is there a way to use the [GEOS concave hull](https://libgeos.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1algorithm_1_1hull_1_1ConcaveHull.html) algorithm from Python, for example from Shapely (or other Python libraries) in a 'natural' way, e.g. relatively close to what is proposed by the [St_ConcaveHull()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html) function implemented in PostGIS?

I've searched for it without any success in:

- https://pygeos.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html
- https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference.html

Comment: use  [alphashape](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Shapely has a binding to the GEOS concave hull implementation  as [shapely.concave_hull](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.concave_hull.html).